# SharePoint Permissions Report

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, permissions

I want to create a SharePoint permissions report using PowerShell. I have looked for multiple options but not getting what I want.

Please see the below format I am looking for. Please help.

And it will be great if read permissions can be excluded. For eg, everyone has access to view or read a SharePoint site. So I don't want that in the report.

Sounds like a simple task, but cant find a solution.

Looking for the below details:

- SharePoint site
- Email id of user who have access
- Permission level of user

Answer (score 0):

Open the PowerShell ISE and run the following script, typing the appropriate values for $Url and $Path variables to specify the SharePoint site address and the report output path:

```
#SPO-specific cmdlets require sharepoint-online module
Install-Module -NameMicrosoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell

$ServiceURL ="https://enterprise-admin.sharepoint.com"
$URL = "https://enterprise.sharepoint.com"
$Path = "C:\Temp\GroupsReport.csv"

#Connect to SharePoint Online
$Cred =  Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -url$ServiceURL -Credential$Cred

#Generating Report
$GroupsData = @()

#get sharepoint online groups powershell
$SiteGroups =Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site$URL
ForEach($Group in $SiteGroups) {
    $GroupsData +=New-Object PSObject-Property @{
        'Group Name' =$Group.Title
        'Permissions' =$Group.Roles -join ","
        'Users' =  $Group.Users -join ","
    }
}

#Export the data to CSV
$GroupsData |Export-Csv $Path-NoTypeInformation
```

For more information, please refer to [here](https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_get_sharepoint_online_permissions.html).

Comment: Thanks.. But I got the result in this format.

"IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count" 

"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","3" 

"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","3"

Comment: OK. Thanks your feedback. :)